# how to write a bash script like the ones used in init.d?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have to write a bash script that makes lot of things. I'd like to print messages as nice as init scripts do. For example:

```
 Doing A... [OK]  
 Doing B... [ERROR]  
 ....
```

Do you know any way to make this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On all my Linux boxes, the code to do that is in the file:

```
/etc/init.d/functions
```

If you include that file (`. /etc/init.d/functions`) and then run your code doing this:

```
action /path/to/prog args
```

you will get the functionality you want.

Comment: thanks, I saw that file and the usage of action is: action $"Doing A..." /path/to/prog args. ;) thanks!

Comment: My linux doesn't have this (xandros, a debian variant, on the eeePC). But having a look in /etc/init.d/*, the files seem to use `/lib/lsb/init-functions` in the same way, calling functions it defines, like  log_begin_msg, log_progress_msg, log_warning_msg,   log_failure_msg and log_end_msg.  One of them also references `/etc/init.d/functions`, but only if the system is redhat.

Answer (score 4):

The `/etc/init.d/*` scripts follow a fairly easy to use template.  Just find one and copy and modify it.

The `[OK]` / `[ERROR]` stuff is done by sourcing the file `/etc/init.d/functions` within your script (at the top generally).

Answer (score 2):

use printf. I like having things color coded too. :)

Here's the preamble I use in my scripts to setup the colors and a few printf statements...

```
#!/bin/bash
# checkload.sh - script to check logs for errors.
#
# Created by Ryan Bray, rbray@xxx.com


set -e

# Text color variables
txtund=$(tput sgr 0 1)    # Underline
txtbld=$(tput bold)       # Bold
txtred=$(tput setaf 1)    # Red
txtgrn=$(tput setaf 2)    # Green
txtylw=$(tput setaf 3)    # Yellow
txtblu=$(tput setaf 4)    # Blue
txtpur=$(tput setaf 5)    # Purple
txtcyn=$(tput setaf 6)    # Cyan
txtwht=$(tput setaf 7)    # White
txtrst=$(tput sgr0)       # Text reset
```

And then I have statements like this that use colors in the output:

```
printf "Checking for descrepancies in $LOAD_DATE$ADD_COMP\n"
DELTAS=$(awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\"" } {print $24,$26,$28}' $COMP_FILE)
if [[ "$DELTAS" == *[1-9]* ]]; then
        printf "%74s[${txtred}FAIL${txtrst}]\n"
        printf "$COMP_FILE contains descrepancies.\n"
        exit 1
else
        printf "%74s[${txtgrn}PASS${txtrst}]\n"
fi
```

Hope this helps!

-Ryan