# bash: echo something to right end of window (right aligned)

Tags: bash

I am looking for producing success/fail messages which are right aligned in bash. An example would be what apache2 produces on executing: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload` etc.

In above example, apache2 produces very nice and concise `[OK]` or `[fail]` message which are right aligned.

Also, would love to know how to get the text red, in case, we are to produce a `[fail]` message.

Comment: Use printf; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199843/bourne-shell-left-right-justify

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

RED=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)

col=80 # change this to whatever column you want the output to start at

if <some condition here>; then
  printf '%s%*s%s' "$GREEN" $col "[OK]" "$NORMAL"
else
  printf '%s%*s%s' "$RED" $col "[FAIL]" "$NORMAL"
fi
```

Comment: @SiegeX: `col=$(tput cols)` is better than hardcoding it and more consistent with the other `tput` uses.  Also, your method eats extra space for the color escapes, which don't actually take any space.  `printf '%s%*s%s' "$GREEN" $col '[OK]' "$NORMAL"` might be cleaner.

Comment: @geek: I decided against `tput cols` and also `tput cup` because the former doesn't give you the flexibility to specify the column (it may not look best at the hairy edge) and the latter requires the row #.

Comment: @SiegeX: You could use `tput hpa` for the latter.

Comment: @geek: that's right, always forget that one. In either case, I didn't realize that with a single `%s` printf was eating space on the non-printable chars. So although I think the way I had it was easier to read, your way is more correct and I'll change it. Thanks

Comment: It's the `%*s` that eats space; `printf` assumes that every character in the corresponding string will take space in the field and right-justify as such; it has no concept of escape sequences beyond `\n` etc. (and doesn't consider even those in computing field widths).

Comment: @geek: btw, I am a Tepper grad. Hope your search goes well

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this thread, might be interesting : [how to write a bash script like the ones used in init.d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494902/how-to-write-a-bash-script-like-the-ones-used-in-init-d)

On Linux CentOS 6.5, i'm using the /etc/init.d/functions file:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/init.d/functions # include the said file

action "Description of the action" command

exit 0
```

assuming `command` returns `0` on success, positive value if an error occurs.
To let the script be easy to read, i use a function call instead of the whole command.

Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

. /etc/init.d/functions

this_will_fail()
{
    # Do some operations...
    return 1
}

this_will_succeed()
{
    # Do other operations...
    return 0
}


action "This will fail"     this_will_fail
action "This will succeed"  this_will_succeed

exit 0
```

resulting in:
[image: console output]
(note : french locale ;-) )

Hope it'll help !

Comment: note that the import of `/etc/init.d/functions` modifies the `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something mostly based on the centos 'functions' script, but more stripped down

```
#!/bin/bash

RES_COL=60
MOVE_TO_COL="printf \\033[${RES_COL}G"

DULL=0
BRIGHT=1

FG_BLACK=30
FG_RED=31
FG_GREEN=32
FG_YELLOW=33
FG_BLUE=34
FG_MAGENTA=35
FG_CYAN=36
FG_WHITE=37

ESC="^[["
NORMAL="${ESC}m"
RESET="${ESC}${DULL};${FG_WHITE};${BG_NULL}m"

BLACK="${ESC}${DULL};${FG_BLACK}m"
RED="${ESC}${DULL};${FG_RED}m"
GREEN="${ESC}${DULL};${FG_GREEN}m"
YELLOW="${ESC}${DULL};${FG_YELLOW}m"
BLUE="${ESC}${DULL};${FG_BLUE}m"
MAGENTA="${ESC}${DULL};${FG_MAGENTA}m"
CYAN="${ESC}${DULL};${FG_CYAN}m"
WHITE="${ESC}${DULL};${FG_WHITE}m"

SETCOLOR_SUCCESS=$GREEN
SETCOLOR_FAILURE=$RED
SETCOLOR_NORMAL=$RESET

echo_success() {
  $MOVE_TO_COL
  printf "["
  printf $SETCOLOR_SUCCESS
  printf $"  OK  "
  printf $SETCOLOR_NORMAL
  printf "]"
  printf "\r"
  return 0
}

echo_failure() {
  $MOVE_TO_COL
  printf "["
  printf $SETCOLOR_FAILURE
  printf $"FAILED"
  printf $SETCOLOR_NORMAL
  printf "]"
  printf "\r"
  return 1
}

action() {
  local STRING rc

  STRING=$1
  printf "$STRING "
  shift
  "$@" && echo_success $"$STRING" || echo_failure $"$STRING"
  rc=$?
  echo
  return $rc
}

action testing true
action testing false
```